# Flood mapping in QGIS 2.4

Tags: qgis, mapping, flood

I am trying to delineate flood-prone areas using QGIS.

I have a vector layer of the river and a DEM of the same area.

I have used the GRASS Module to get watershed by using `r.watershed` and I have also used `r.water.outlet` to get the basin.

I don't know what to do next to get the flood-prone area. Any suggestions?